# If checkbox checked and fields input required are not empty, change class of button

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to combine the `checkbox` is `checked` with keyup function that give info when write to the `required` fields.

I almost did it, the problem is that if both conditions are `true` (fields not empty and checkbox is checked) the `submit` only change `class` when `keyup` function are activated. So if I write the fields and next check the `checkbox` didn't work because the last thing was a check. If I check the box first and next fill the `inputs` it's work's because the last thing was `keyup`. I tried with `keyup` and `change`, but this don't work for me because it's not for change, if only is checkbox is :checked. You can see live [here](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/inscripciones.php). Required input's are "nota media", "titular" and the checkbox.

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    var fields = $(".ss-item-required").find("select, textarea, input").serializeArray();
    $.each(fields, function(i, field) {
        if ((!field.value) && ($("#customCheck1").is(':checked'))) {
            alert(field.name + ' is required');
        } else {
            $('.btn-inscripcion').removeClass( "disabled" );
        }
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form-inscripciones" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="form-group-row align-items-center">
        <div class="container" style="max-width: 600px;">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Nombre</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Nombre</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Apellidos</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Apellidos</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">NIF</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">NIF</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Fecha de nacimiento</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Domicilio</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Domicilio</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">CP</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">CP</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Localidad</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Localidad</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Provincia</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Provincia</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Teléfono solicitante</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Teléfono solicitante</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">E-mail</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">E-mail</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Curso que estudia</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Curso que estudia</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Facultad o escuela</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Facultad o escuela</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Titulación</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Titulación</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto ss-item-required">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Nota media</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Nota media</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-section small-header bg-left rosa">
        <div style="max-width: calc(34em + 5vw);">
            <h1>DATOS <br> PADRE Y MADRE</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="max-width: 600px;">
        <div class="form-group-row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Nombre padre / Tutor</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Nombre padre / Tutor</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Nombre madre / Tutora</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Nombre madre / Tutora</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Profesión padre / Tutor</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Profesión padre / Tutor</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Profesión madre / Tutora</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Profesión madre / Tutora</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Teléfono de contacto</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Teléfono de contacto</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-section small-header bg-left rosa">
        <div style="max-width: calc(34em + 5vw);">
            <h1>DATOS BANCARIOS</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="max-width: 900px;">
        <div class="form-group-row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">IBAN</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">IBAN</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto ss-item-required">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Titular</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">Titular</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mx-auto form-inscripcion-end-group ss-item-required">
                <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">  
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="normas" id="customCheck1" required>  
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">He leído y acepto las <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">condiciones</a></label>  
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="confirm" class="btn-inscripcion disabled">Enviar formulario</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a flag... You have to let the loop execute entirely. If there is something incorrect found during the loop, the flag is used to retain that information.

---

**EDIT**

I checked [your website](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/inscripciones.php) carefully this time... And tested my solution.

This line was definitely wrong:

```
var fields = $(".ss-item-required")
.find("select, textarea, input").serializeArray();
```

Because the `.find()` method only returns elements from the **last** `.ss-item-required` element. So you weren't checking all required field...

I changed it to:

```
var fields = $("select, textarea, input",".ss-item-required");
```

It gets all `select, textarea, input` in the `.ss-item-required` context. So you now really have all the required elements.

Then... The `input`s does not all have a `name` attribute... That is a problem because it is used in the `alert()`... And may be a problem when you'll submit the `form`.

For now... In order to have a relevant `alert()` text, I used the associated label's text instead...

```
$('input').on('change', function() {

  // Get the collection of all required fields
  var fields = $("select, textarea, input",".ss-item-required");

  // Flag
  var okToEnable = true;

  fields.each(function(i, field) {

    if ( field.type == "text" && field.value=="" ) {

      // Get the label's text
      var label_text = $(field).prev("div").find(".input-group-text").text();

      alert(label_text + ' is required');

      // if incorrect at least once, turn the flag to false
      okToEnable = false;

      // Exit the each loop to avoid alerting more than once
      return false;
    }

    if ( field.type == "checkbox" && !field.checked ) {

      // Get the label's text
      var label_text = $(field).next("label").text();

      alert(label_text + ' is required');

      // if incorrect at least once, turn the flag to false
      okToEnable = false;

      // Exit the each loop to avoid alerting more than once
      return false;
    }

  });

  // After the loop, act based on the flag
  if(okToEnable && $("#customCheck1").is(':checked')){
    $('.btn-inscripcion').removeClass( "disabled" );
  }
});
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that code but don't work. When I Keyup any input it removed the disabled class, that's only should happen when I write all the required inputs...

Comment: mmm Try to change this part of the condition: `(field.value!="")` There's always a value... Even empty. I edited.

Comment: I updated the code but still happening, sorry. You can check here, try to write any input and see how the script remove the class of the button: http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/inscripciones.php

Comment: I see... Try the last edit of my answer. Since the checkbox is the last input a user will check, better use the `change` event and have the checked condition outside the loop.

Comment: I made an edit... I fully tested my solution this time. ;)

Comment: Work's now! So now I having a doubt: Let the javascript alert or use the required alert of the native browser, what is better? What you think.

Comment: The `alert()` is not the cutest thing you can do, for sure... There is many ways to show a message to user. It's up to you.